# Wrapping field into a message vs marking it optional in proto3

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Note: All this pertains to protocol buffers version 3.

Let us say we have a message

```
message Foo {
  int32 weight_in_lbs;
}
```

The producer of this message wants to stop producing the weight in lbs and instead wants to produce it in kgs.

So we deprecate the lbs field and add a kgs field.

```
message Foo {
  int32 weight_in_lbs [deprecated = true];
  int32 weight_in_kgs;
}
```

The producer being distributed (multiple servers) can't upgrade in one go. So at one point we will have producers producing messages of the old and the new message type.

The consumer should ideally check both `weight_in_lbs` and `weight_in_kgs` and prefer the latter if it's available, otherwise fall back on the former. But in proto3, it's not possible to check if a field is truly not set or is actually been set to the default value by the producer. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3) recommends either:

1. wrapping the field in a message, so that we are able to use `HasField()`
2. marking the field as optional (they say this is not recommended)

Which of these options is preferable? Is there a 3rd option? Is there something wrong with my programming pattern where the consumer tries to read both the old and new fields and chooses from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you have no problem: 0 kg equals 0 lbs. But if the fields were e.g. degrees Fahrenheit and Celsius, there indeed need to be a way to distinguish presence.

If you want to make the transition simultaneously on both producers and consumers, using `optional` on the new field seems reasonable.

The alternative is to wait for all producers to have been updated to set both fields, and only after that start changing the consumers to use the new field.